# Can I use regex to match every third occurrence of a specific character?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string containing some delimited values:

```
1.95;1.99;1.78;10.9;11.45;10.5;25.95;26;45;21.2
```

What I'd like to achieve is a split by every third occurence of a semicolon, so my resulting `String[]` should contain this:

```
result[0] = "1.95;1.99;1.78";
result[1] = "10.9;11.45;10.5";
result[2] = "25.95;26;45";
result[3] = "21.2";
```

So far I've tried several regex solutions, but all I could get to was finding any patterns that are between the semi colons. For example:

```
(?<=^|;)[^;]*;?[^;]*;?[^;]*
```

Which matches the values I want, so that makes it impossible to use `split()` or am I missing something?

Unfortunately I can only supply the pattern used and have no possibility to add some looping through results of the above pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String re = "(?<=\\G[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*);";
String text = "1.95;1.99;1.78;10.9;11.45;10.5;25.95;26;45;21.2";
String[] result = Pattern.compile(re).split(text);
```

Now the result is what you want
Hint: \G in java's regex is a boundary matcher like `^`,  it means 'end of previous match'

Comment: Great! This works exactly as desired! Especially the \G used to find the end of the previous match.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this instead:

```
String s = "1.95;1.99;1.78;10.9;11.45;10.5;25.95;26;45;21.2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?;.*?;.*?;");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int lastEnd = -1;
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
    lastEnd = m.end();
}
System.out.println(s.substring(lastEnd));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Since Java doesn't support indefinite-length lookbehind assertions (which you need if you want to check whether there are 3, 6, 9 or 3*n values before the current semicolon), you can't use `split()` for this. Your regex works perfectly with a "find all" approach, but if you can't apply that in your situation, you're out of luck.

In other languages (.NET-based ones, for example), the following regex would work:

```
;(?<=^(?:[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like:

```
 ([0-9.]*;){3}
```

not work for your needs?  The caveat is that there will be a trailing ; at the end of the group.  You might be able to tweak the expression to trim that off however.

I just reread your question, and although this simple expression will work for matching groups, if you need to supply it to the `split()` method, it will unfortunately not do the job.